# TSQL - using IN with PIVOT

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

Quick question that's bugging me.

When using PIVOT in T-SQL, can the 'FOR..IN' portion reference a table rather than a defined list of values?

Example, instead of something like:-

```
PIVOT (Count(widgets) For Team IN ([Dave],[Peter],[John]....etc))
```

Could you do something like:-

```
PIVOT (Count(widgets) for Team IN (SELECT TeamLeader FROM Teams))
```

I can find no reference to confirm whether or not this is possible.

Comment: short answer, no. you'd need to look into generating dynamic sql.

Comment: So, if not possible, how could I go about doing something like this?  Any pointers in general?

Comment: This is a good question, even though the answer is negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, this is not possible.**

The [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator syntax dictates that these values is entered as a list:

> ```
> ...
>
> IN ( [first pivoted column], 
>
>      [second pivoted column],
>
> ...
> ...
>
>      [last pivoted column])
> ```

But you can do this dynamically, something like:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(Teamleader)
                      FROM Teams
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');


SELECT @query = ' SELECT ' + @cols +
                ' FROM AnotherTable a
                  PIVOT 
                  (
                     Count(widgets) For Team IN (' + @cols + ')' +
                  ') p';
execute(@query);
```